# Do Python functions modify their arguments?

Tags: python, list, function

I was in my computer science class today and the teacher put a piece of python coding on the board and said he couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. He was showing us functions and said:

```
def app(x):
    x.append(" ")
    print(x)

def ext(x,y):
    x.extend(y)
    print(y)

nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
numbers = [7,8,9,10]

app(nums)
ext(nums,numbers)

print("End of program")
```

The code was meant to show how when you don't type

```
return x
```

in the function then the variable doesn't change when you return to the main program however when he ran the program, the first function added the space and kept it there when it returned resulting in the following text being printed...

```
['1','2','3','4','5','6',' ']
['1','2','3','4','5','6',' ','7','8','9','10']
End of program
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: You are manipulating the object referenced by `nums` and `x`. You are not manipulating what `x` refers to itself. If references are your finger pointing at the moon (and not the moon itself), you didn't change what your finger pointed at but actually followed the finger and planted a flag on the moon.

Comment: You need a better teacher... The difference between an object and a reference to that object (which is actually what is being passed around in this sample) is very, very basic.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code...

Comment: Neither, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to. Indeed, it's the Python convention **not** to `return` when the argument is changed in-place.

Comment: @DragonstoneJosh: there is nothing wrong with the code. If your teacher didn't understand what was going on, you need a better teacher.

Comment: This cannot possible be from the teacher, as any teacher knows this. This must instead be a rephrased question, perhaps that a teacher put on a homework set or something.

Comment: @mixedmath: You underestimate the human capacity for ignorance (and arrogance). Not all teachers, unfortunately, can teach, or indeed know the subject matter in the first place. (I've experienced this first-hand myself.)

Comment: @Cameron while that may be true I think calling the teacher an idiot may be counterproductive (and I tend to think this was not verbatim what the teacher was saying and showing... since OP is clearly confused, it is entirely possible he mis-understood what the teacher was saying)

Answer (score 2):

You say that the point was to demonstrate that a list won't be changed unless it is returned.  That is false.  The list is a mutable object.  When you pass it (**by name**) to a function and change it, it will be changed.  If you don't want the change, you need to work with a copy.

Comment: +1 for recognizing the question in there and explaining about mutable objects

Comment: Although, I would point out that this is passing "by reference" and not "by name". You should probably edit your answer to include that change.

Comment: This is not passing by reference. "Pass by reference" is a technique where the argument in the function is a reference to a name in the caller.  That isn't possible in Python.  But you are right that it is not "pass by name" either!  The best term for Python is "pass by sharing".

Comment: The best term remains in dispute but is perhaps [pass by assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) or _pass by the name of the object reference_, for which _pass by name_ seems an adequate shorthand (outside the context of Algol).  But I'm not a CS type, so feel free to correct this impression.

Answer (score 0):

```
def app(x):
    return x + [" "]


def ext(x,y):
    return x + y
```

might be what you are trying to do ... im not sure, this will not alter either of the original lists, but will return a new list as the result